# auto scroll in a dynamic text box (as3)

Tags: actionscript-3, textbox, flash-cs4

I have a dynamic text box called logtxt. I add text to this whenever i click on my box object.(this works fine) I have a UIScrollBar attached to the text box(still works). But I need it to automatically scroll to the bottom whenever I add text.

I don't even know where to start so if anyone give me some hints...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [scrollV property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#scrollV) of `TextField`.

Comment: `myTextField.scrollV(myTextField.numLines);`

Answer (score 1):

Typically you have a function that updates the text field if you're looking to make it force scroll to the end of the textbox when you add text.

The \r is a carriage return for starting a new line each time you add content to the box. Omit if you dont want a new line per entry.

```
function log(e){
     myTextField.text = myTextField.text + " \r " +": " +String(e);
     myTextField.scrollV = myTextField.maxScrollV;
}
```